# Acceder a propiedades o atributos de un objeto de una clase creado al vuelo

Tags: c#, poo

Supongamos que tengo este codigo;

```
            new List<Int32>().Add(Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

¿Podría tener acceso de alguna manera al numero que he introducido en la lista? Al no haber un objeto como tal no se si seria posible algo así...

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Add en ese caso devuelve un void no una lista. Lo que se podria hacer es lo siguiente para este caso puntual, de acceder todo sin variables.

```
new List<Int32>() { Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) }[0]
```

El ejemplo completo seria y este y funciona OK

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si vos queres usarlo despues tenes que almacenarlo en una variable y luego accederla.

Saludos y espero te sirva.

Comment: El ejemplo es un mero ejemplo... mi pregunta es mas generica, es decir, cuando yo creo un objeto al vuelo, con el New y llamando a uno de sus metodos directamente, ¿Puedo en tiempo de ejecucion, mas adealnte, acceder a ese objeto que se a creado en "algun sitio"?
O como no he creado el objeto ya no se puede tener acceso a el...

P:D: Tu ejemplo no compila, ¿La sintaxis es correcta=

Comment: En teoria al crearlo al vuelo como tu dices.. Esta operación/Acción se crea y se destruye inmediatamente a menos que guardes lo que te Retorna en una variable  ej.   var list = new... Y lo que haya realizado o retornado  estara en list..

Comment: Ahi edite la respuesta con el ejemplo completo. Si queres disponer de un valor despues y no en misma instruccion tenes que guardarlo en una variable aparte.